# Получить массив, который состоит из текстового содержимого ссылок внутри списка: getTextFromUl(ul) ---> ["Link1", "Link2", "Link3"]

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, как поменять содержимое массива на его текстовый контент, пробовал через innerHTML и textContent. Исправьте меня пожалуйста.

```
const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
const list = document.querySelectorAll('li')
function getTextFrom(ul) {
    return [...list].textContent
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul><span></span>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
  
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```js
function getTextFrom(ul) {    
    const list = ul.querySelectorAll('li')
    return [...list].map(item=> item.textContent)
}

const ul = document.querySelector('ul')

console.log(getTextFrom(ul))
```

```html
<div>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul><span></span>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
```

Comment: да, спасибо большое